# System.Net.HttpClient throws uploading files: The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, upload, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on a project that have some runners where each runner could be uploading files simultaneously. Arbitrarily I would get an 'The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations' error.

We have seen it happening with small (5Mb~10Mb) and big files too (1Gb~2Gb). We have even tried the exact same files and we are able to repro it sometimes.

Our setup has NTLM auth, self-signed cert and self-hosted with OWIN/Katana. All written using .Net.

**It only happens (so far) on VMs, we have not sen the problem using physical machines, although some of those VMs are really powerful**

This is my code:

**Client**

```
public Guid Upload(string filePath, Guid taskId)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)) { throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be empty.", "filePath"); }

    var key = Guid.Empty;
    var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);

    using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        var content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        content.Headers.Add("TaskId", taskId.ToString());
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileInfo.Name;
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        content.Headers.ContentLength = fileInfo.Length;

        key = HttpClient.PostGet<Guid>(content, "https://localhost:1234/Files/Upload");
    }

    return key;
}

public T PostGet<T>(string url, HttpContent content, IDictionary<string, string> headers)
{
    using (var client = httpClient) // <-- look below to check how we build this
    {
        client.AddHeaders(headers);
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        try
        {
            response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

            ensureSuccessStatusCode(response);

            var jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var obj = Deserialize<T>(jsonResult);

            return obj;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}

private System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient
{
    get
    {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = null;

        if (authenticationEnabled)
        {
            if (credentials == null)
            {
                client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new CertValidatingWebRequestHandler()
                {
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new CertValidatingWebRequestHandler()
                {
                    Credentials = credentials
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        }

        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimeOutInMilliseconds);
        return client;
    }
}

public class CertValidatingWebRequestHandler : WebRequestHandler
{
    public CertValidatingWebRequestHandler()
    {
        this.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateRemoteCert;
    }

    private bool ValidateRemoteCert(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**SERVER**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
{
    return await upload(Guid.Empty);
}

private async Task<IHttpActionResult> upload(Guid appendToKey)
{
    if (Request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.Equals("application/octet-stream", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var taskId = Guid.Empty;

        if (Request.Headers.Contains("TaskId"))
        {
            var taskIdValue = Request.Headers.GetValues("TaskId").FirstOrDefault();
            taskId = new Guid(taskIdValue);
        }

        var fileName = Request.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
        fileName = fileName.Trim(' ', '"');

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var key = Guid.NewGuid();
        var directoryPath = string.Empty;

        if (appendToKey == Guid.Empty)
        {
            directoryPath = createStorageDirectory(key);
        }
        else
        {
            var fileInfo = fileStorage.GetFileInfo(appendToKey);

            if (fileInfo == null)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("File with key {0} was not found.", appendToKey));
            }

            directoryPath = fileInfo.Path;
        }

        var filePath = fileSystem.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);

        using (var httpStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        handleResponse(key, directoryPath, fileName, appendToKey, taskId, t);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        deleteStorageFolder(key);

                        logger.Log(LogType.Error, e);
                        throw;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        return Ok(key);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }
}
```

**FULL ERROR**

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations.
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.TryStartWriteSync(Int32 bytesRead)
       at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NotSupportedException: The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations.
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.TryStartWriteSync(Int32 bytesRead)
       at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)<---
```

Sorry for the long post, but i figured the more info the better would be for you.

I'm trying to disable auth and certs to isolate the issue even further. I'll update later.

Thanks in advance. Any help/Suggestion/Idea is more than welcome!!!!

Comment: Hi Lale, did you ever got to the root of this problem?

Comment: Hi d@dennis, we ended up taking a diff path. After doing some research I was pretty sure the problem was in the way the client was streaming the files...you know...mishandling them by closing it too early, disposing, etc. But that's just a hunch. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.